# getChildAt(index) returns null

Tags: android

I have a problem getting null by `getChildAt(index)` function. There are views added programmatic, however some do work but some don't......I check the hierarchy through monitor and ensure the index is correct, so I cannot understand where the problem is.

here is the part work that `getChildAt(index)` can get the child perfectly.

```
        Cursor aCursor = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{danceId, (i+1)+""});
        int index = 0;
        if (aCursor.getCount()>0){
            while(aCursor.moveToNext()){
                EditText ansText = new EditText(activity);
                ansText.setText(aCursor.getString(0));
                ansText.setTag(R.id.da_id,aCursor.getString(1));
                ansText.setTag(R.id.edit_flag, false);
                ansText.addTextChangedListener(new editFlagListener(ansText));

                ansView.addView(ansText, index);
                index++;
            }
        } else {
            EditText ansText = new EditText(activity);
            ansText.setTag(R.id.edit_flag, false);
            ansText.addTextChangedListener(new editFlagListener(ansText));

            ansView.addView(ansText, index);                
        }
```

and here is the problem part. I add child view by a button click.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LinearLayout ans = null;
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.q1_add:
            ans = a1;
            break;
        case R.id.q2_add:
            ans = a2;
            break;
        case R.id.q3_add:
            ans = a3;
            break;
        case R.id.q4_add:
            ans = a4;
            break;
        case R.id.q5_add:
            ans = a5;
            break;
        case R.id.q6_add:
            ans = a6;
            break;
        case R.id.q7_add:
            ans = a7;
            break;
        case R.id.q8_add:
            ans = a8;
            break;
        case R.id.q9_add:
            ans = a9;
            break;
        case R.id.q10_add:
            ans = a10;
            break;
        }

        if (ans != null){
            EditText ansText = new EditText(activity);
            ans.addView(ansText, ans.getChildCount());
        }
    }
```

and finally the part how I get child (in which return null for the child added by button), the last run sentence is the if-clause:

```
                for(int j=0; j<ansView.getChildCount(); j++){
                    Log.i(TAG, "text no.:"+j);
                    EditText ansText = (EditText)ansView.getChildAt(j);
                    if ( (boolean)ansText.getTag(R.id.edit_flag) == true){
                          ...
                    }
                }
```

The Error I have got(in this example I have 5 child where 5th child is added by button):

```
08-15 10:48:30.021: I/OneToOneNote(3888): dq id:1
08-15 10:48:30.021: I/OneToOneNote(3888): text no.:0
08-15 10:48:30.021: I/OneToOneNote(3888): text no.:1
08-15 10:48:30.021: I/OneToOneNote(3888): text no.:2
08-15 10:48:30.021: I/OneToOneNote(3888): text no.:3
08-15 10:48:30.021: I/OneToOneNote(3888): text no.:4
08-15 10:48:30.021: D/AndroidRuntime(3888): Shutting down VM
08-15 10:48:30.021: W/dalvikvm(3888): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4154eba8)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888): Process: com.garland.digital.hk.BNI.Supreme, PID: 3888
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.garland.digital.hk.BNI.Supreme.OneToOneNote.onOptionsItemSelected(OneToOneNote.java:142)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performOptionsItemSelected(Fragment.java:1608)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchOptionsItemSelected(FragmentManager.java:2012)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:378)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:115)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-15 10:48:30.021: E/AndroidRuntime(3888):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: opps, sorry for that. I get a NullPointerException error

Comment: post it here for us to debug

Comment: edited. Is it understanding enough?

Comment: No, you did not even put what index is it.

Comment: sorry, what u mean is.....?

Comment: On what index is the null pointer exception occurs in the `forloop`, try to debug it.

Comment: the index at the problem part. It always occurs the error at the last child which added by button click. When I not click the button, it goes well.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. Also, the first code snippet does not use `getChildAt()` as you claim.

Comment: Suggestion: use an array or `List` for your questions and answers

Comment: And what are you trying to accomplish with the `Cursor` and the `while` loop? Are you creating a list of views? If so, you should look at using a `ListView` instead. It creates views dynamically for you, much like you are trying to do here.

Comment: A lot to explain of why not using ListView......by the way, thanks for suggesting using array but I think we should deal with the current problem first...